# In phalcon php how to save multiple record in database table

Tags: php, phalcon

I have following code

```
foreach ($cartList as $domainDetail) {

        $values = array();

        $values['customerId']   = $user['userId'];
        $values['domainName']   = $domainDetail['domain'];
        $values['price']        = $domainDetail['amount'];
        $values['status']       = 'active';
        $values['creationDate'] = date('Y-m-d');

        //create object of Domain
        $domain = new Domain();

        for($index = 0; $index < count($years); $index++) {
            $year = $years[$index];

            $values['expiryDate']   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+' . $year. 'year'));

            //save domain data to the database
            $domain->save($values);
        }

        $domainId = $domain->getDomainId();

        if (empty($domainIds)) {
            $domainIds = $domainId;
        } else {
            $domainIds = $domainIds . ',' . $domainId;
        }

        if ($domainNames != '') {
            $domainNames = $domainNames . ',' . $values['domainName'];
        } else {
            $domainNames = $values['domainName'];
        }
    }
```

When I execute this code in my table the entry for expiry date field i for every save up to for loop execute will bt the last expiry date only.
This skip first expiry date

Comment: Where does `$years` come from? Also, it'll always only save the last expiryDate since the for-loop overwrites the value.